Relationship between angles at Fermat point in high dimensions
It is well known that at the Fermat point of a triangle (no angle $\geq 120$ degrees), the three angles are all $120$ degrees, or $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. In 1 dimension, the Fermat point of a segment is not unique, but the angles are all $\frac{2\pi}{2}$. What about high dimension Fermat points, that is, point with smallest sum of distances to $n+1$ points in $n$ dimension?
Here is an example: Fermat point of a tetrahedron
I calculated the cosines of the six angles. Say the vertices are $A, B, C, D$ in order. Then: $\cos \angle AOB=\cos \angle COD=-\frac{1}{5}$, $\cos \angle BOC=\cos \angle AOD=\frac{1}{15}$, $\cos \angle AOC=\cos\angle BOD=-\frac{13}{15}$. They are not all equal, but they form three pairs each with vertices $A, B, C, D$.
I am wondering if there is any relationship between the angles at the Fermat point in general and in higher dimensions.

In $R^3$, the interior Fermat point $O$ satisfies $\angle AOB=\angle COD$, $\angle AOC=\angle BOD$ and $\angle AOD=\angle BOC$. If we denote them by $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, then they satisfy
\begin{equation}\label{c}
\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=1.
\end{equation}
Proof. At four vertices, we put frictionless pulleys over which pass strings knotted at $O$. Each string is attached with a weight of equal weight. The figure shows the situation for the classic two-dimensional Fermat point (the figure is from Fermat's point from five perspectives)

The system will reach the state with lowest energy, that is, the sum $OA+OB+OC+OD$ is minimal. Note that the forces at $O$ must be balanced. Since the weights are equal, the force vectors at $O$ can be assumed as unit vectors $v_1$ through $v_4$. From $v_1+v_2=-(v_3+v_4)$, it follows that the angle between $v_1$ and $v_2$ is equal to the angle between $v_3$ and $v_4$. This is also true for the other two pairs. Hence, $\angle AOB=\angle COD$ and so on.
To prove \eqref{c}, we establish Cartesian coordinates with $v_1=(\cos\frac{\alpha}{2},-\sin\frac{\alpha}{2},0)$, $v_2=(\cos\frac{\alpha}{2},\sin\frac{\alpha}{2},0)$. Then the other two vectors are
\begin{equation*}
v_3=(-\cos\frac{\alpha}{2},-\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\theta,-\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin\theta), \quad v_4=(-\cos\frac{\alpha}{2},\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\theta,\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin\theta)
\end{equation*}
which satisfy $v_1\cdot v_2=v_3\cdot v_4=\cos\alpha$. Now we have
\begin{align*}
\cos\beta=v_1\cdot v_3=v_2\cdot v_4=-\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2}+\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\theta,\\
\cos\gamma=v_1\cdot v_4=v_2\cdot v_3=-\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\theta.
\end{align*}
Canceling $\theta$, we find
\begin{equation*}
\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma=-1.
\end{equation*}
